# Add nftables map element using libnftables-json API from python

Tags: python, nftables

I am trying to dynamically add a map element using the nftables JSON API from python. In my firewall I have the following map in the `router` table in the `ip` family:

```
map port_forwards {
    type inet_service: ipv4_addr . inet_service;
}
```

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do:

```py
import nftables

nft_cmd = {"nftables": [
    { "add": { "element":{
        "family": "ip",
        "table": "router",
        "name": "port_forwards",
        "elem": { "map": {
            "key": "80",
            "data": "172.16.0.1 . 80"
        }}
    }}}
]}

nft = nftables.Nftables()
nft.json_validate(nft_cmd)
rc, _output, error = nft.json_cmd(nft_cmd)
if rc != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"Error running nftables command: {error}")
```

This results in the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error running nftables command: internal:0:0-0: Error: Unexpected JSON type object for immediate value.

internal:0:0-0: Error: Invalid set.

internal:0:0-0: Error: Parsing command array at index 0 failed.
```

I assume I am mis-understanding the spec somehow (https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libnftables1/libnftables-json.5.en.html), but I can't figure out the correct usage.

UPDATE: I have discovered `nft` can echo your command in json format. This is the command:

```
sudo nft -e -j add element ip router port_forwards '{80 : 172.16.0.1 . 8080 }'
```

and the response pretty-printed:

```
{"nftables": [
    {"add": {"element": {
        "family": "ip",
        "table": "router",
        "name": "port_forwards",
        "elem": {"set": [[
            80,
            {"concat": ["172.16.0.1", 8080]}
        ]]}
    }}}
]}
```

Unfortunately copying this into the above python code still results in the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `"elem"` property takes the array directly instead of being wrapped in a `"set"` object. This was hinted at by the error:

```
Unexpected JSON type object for immediate value.
```

The working code is shown below:

```
import nftables

nft_cmd = {"nftables": [
    { "add": { "element":{
        "family": "ip",
        "table": "router",
        "name": "port_forwards",
        "elem": [[
            80,
            {"concat": ["172.16.0.1", 8080]}
        ]]
    }}}
]}


nft = nftables.Nftables()
nft.json_validate(nft_cmd)
rc, _output, error = nft.json_cmd(nft_cmd)
if rc != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"Error running nftables command: {error}")
```